# how to properly test if-else condition in a useReducer switch case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I am learning React and currently reviewing useReducer. I am trying to create a keypad that resets when an incorrect entry is entered. This code works when the `'add-entry'` case is `[ ...state, action.value ]` but when I introduce the if statement, it seems to fail. I can't figure out why the condition evaluates to false. When I test the values in the button handler, they are equivalent. Any ideas on what the issue could be?

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Keypad() {
    const code = [ "1","2","3","4","5","6" ];
    let access = '';

    const reducer = ( state, action ) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'add-entry':
                if ( state === code.slice(0,state.length) ) {
                    return [ ...state, action.value ] 
                } else {
                    return []
                }
            default:
                return state
        }
    };

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

    function buttonHandler( event ) {
        console.log('state', state)
        console.log('code', code.slice(0,state.length)) 

        dispatch({ type:'add-entry', value: event.target.value })       
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>Your code is: <strong>{ code }</strong></div>
            <div>Current entry: <strong>{ state }</strong></div>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={buttonHandler} value="1">1</button>
            <button onClick={buttonHandler} value="2">2</button>
            <button onClick={buttonHandler} value="3">3</button>
            <button onClick={buttonHandler} value="4">4</button>
            <button onClick={buttonHandler} value="5">5</button>
            <button onClick={buttonHandler} value="6">6</button>
            <br/>
            <div>Access: <strong>{ access }</strong></div>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Keypad/>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: Chek out this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-rubin-eioxr?file=/src/App.js). It's usually better to right the reducer outside of the function because it is independant of each render. Then you have to pass the code somehow, here I added it to state. It looked to me it was easier to store `code` and `access` in a string. In your if statement you comparing two arrays, first time the `'add-entry'` is dispatched, two empty arrays are compared, which always return false, because their references are compared.

Comment: @c0m1t thanks! the input was very helpful. I ended up using strings for code and access and combing them into one object in useReducer.